# How to retrieve and remove embedded document spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

There I am stuck, how to remove embedded document in mongodb. I am using spring data mongodb criteria, I am doing it like the following:

```
// database

"_id" : ObjectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db7"),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.metadata.Metadata",
    "preferenceType" : "SHOPPING",
    "subtypes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6"),
            "leftValue" : "VEG",
            "rightValue" : "NON_VEG",
            "preferencePoint" : 0
        }
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-05-29T10:20:01.610Z"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-05-29T10:20:01.610Z")


// query

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(),
                    new Update().pull("subtypes", Query.query(Criteria.where("subtypes._id").is(new objectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6"))),Metadata.class);
```

What i am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subtypes` is in nested objects so you should first pass this in [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is matched first matching array elements of given conditions. Update query as :

```
db.updateMulti.update({"subtypes":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":ObjectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6")}}},
{"$pull":{"subtypes":{"_id":ObjectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6")}}})
```

this query pull exact matching array elements from `subtypes` array .

And with the help of this [spring elemMatch](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/127899-help-with-and-and-elemmatch-in-spring-data-mongodb) ( *not that much expertise in spring mongo* ) I converted this query in spring format as below :

```
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query( 
where("subtypes").elemMatch(where("_id").is(ew objectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6"))).pull(
  pull("subtypes", Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new objectId("55683d51e4b0b6050c5b0db6"))),Metadata.class
));
```

this above spring query not tested I hope you will convert mongo update query in spring mongo query format.