# How to delete an item from array of items in MongoDB using Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I want to delete an item from array of items where if some condition gets true.
For eg:
I have 1000's of records which each have `caseDetails` array and inside that I have many items.
I want to pass in a `caseId` and delete any `caseDetails` items that match that id.
Below is the MongoDB data for explanation let say I have two data for example now I want that if caseId=24894006(That i have passed) exits(Not to write new query) in the DB then it should get deleted.

1)First DB data

```
{
    "_id": "60f8fcbe8f67d30784c45561",
    "messageType": "e",
    "sendDate": "2021-07-22T05:06:04.023Z",
    "assigneeId": 600003,
    "customerId": 58004,
    "subject": "Email Test 1[#24894006]",
    "mailAnswered": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "caseDetails": [
        {
            "caseId": 24894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 34894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 44894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        }

    ]
},  
{
    "_id": "60f8fcbe8f67d30784c45561",
    "messageType": "e",
    "sendDate": "2021-07-22T05:06:04.023Z",
    "assigneeId": 600003,
    "customerId": 58004,
    "subject": "Email Test 1[#24894006]",
    "mailAnswered": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "caseDetails": [
        {
            "caseId": 24894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 34894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 44894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        }
    ]
}
```

So as per above example the output in DB should be like:

```
{
    "_id": "60f8fcbe8f67d30784c45561",
    "messageType": "e",
    "sendDate": "2021-07-22T05:06:04.023Z",
    "assigneeId": 600003,
    "customerId": 58004,
    "subject": "Email Test 1[#24894006]",
    "mailAnswered": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "caseDetails": [
        {
            "caseId": 34894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 44894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        }

    ]
},  
{
    "_id": "80f8fcbe8f67d30784c45561",
    "messageType": "e",
    "sendDate": "2021-07-22T05:06:04.023Z",
    "assigneeId": 600003,
    "customerId": 58004,
    "subject": "Email Test 1[#24894006]",
    "mailAnswered": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "caseDetails": [
        {
            "caseId": 54894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        },
        {
            "caseId": 64894006,
            "employeeId": 600003
        }
    ]
}
```

From caseDetails caseId = 24894006(Whole object)

I have also coded:

```
@Override
  public List<Email> unlinkMessageCaseDetailsByCaseId(MessageFilter messageFilter) {
    Criteria finalCriteria = handleCriteria(messageFilter);
    Query query = query(finalCriteria);
    // Update update = new Update().pull("caseDetails", Collections.singletonMap("caseId", messageFilter.getCaseId()));
    List<Email> uMono = mongoTemplate.find(query, Email.class).collectList().block();
    return uMono;
  }
```

This is the repository I'm using

```
@MongoRepository
public interface EmailRepository 
         extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Email, String>,
                 MessageRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530723/how-to-retrieve-and-remove-embedded-document-spring-data-mongodb

Comment: This has nothing to do with JPA.